# How can I port jQuery code for resizing Bootstrap modal windows to AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am resizing Bootstrap modal windows based on their content with a little help of jQuery. The whole thing is basically working as a custom-built lightbox. Now I would be very happy if I could use AngularJS to populate the website with data.

First of all, I'm aware that I should ideally migrate to native AngularJS UI Bootstrap. However, it seems to me that the frontend is at the stage of development where ditching the work which has been put into making vanilla Bootstrap work as expected, would not be feasible. Especially, when considering the lack of my JavaScript coding skills and the fact that I had to put a considerable effort even into this simple jQuery script.

Here's an extremely simplified version of my perfectly working static code:

```
<a href="#modal-000" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-000">
    Open modal #000
</a><br/>

<div class="modal" id="modal-000" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" id="modal-dialog-000">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                I am modal #000.
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a><br/>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/4rLrHBa.png" id="image-000"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // Resizing modal window
    $('#modal-000').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        var modalWidth = $('#image-000').width() + 30;
        $('#modal-dialog-000').css('width', modalWidth);
    });
</script>
```

And here's a jsFiddle which also includes the hypothetical AngularJS part: http://jsfiddle.net/evaldass/xy3zu0w1/

How can I achieve this inside a ng-repeat? Should jQuery be removed altogether? Or maybe it's possible to choose a quicker path that would be not very puristic? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, [it's already been done](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. By "I should ideally migrate to native AngularJS UI Bootstrap" I had this project in mind. It's just my current JS coding skills make it to be an overwhelming task at the moment. So, I decided to ask if there is a simpler way for me.

Also, if I'm not mistaken, moving my code to native AngularJS UI Bootstrap would only be the first part of the equation to solve my problem.

Comment: Combining jQuery and AngularJS is rarely simple, because they just don't work the same way. AngularJS monitors changes to the data, then modifies the DOM, while jQuery modifies the DOM directly. Use AngularJS's built-in [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) via `angular.element`, or go with the modified Bootstrap UI.